# Authentication Workflow with Azure App Service and React

Tags: c#, azure

I am building a new React website that consumes some REST services hosted on Azure App Service (ASP.NET Web API).  The React application will require customers to log into the site.  The login process follows the standard "Forgot Password" which will email the customer a code to reset their password online.  Currently, there is not a customer database/datastore.

My question is... is there an already built-in authentication software package that handles identity, authentication, and self-serviced account management (2FA, forgot password email, verification via sms, etc.) either UI or API?  In other words, I would prefer not to build that identity and auth/n into the ASP.NET Web API, but rather have React deal with it directly.  The React login experience needs to be integrated with the site, and not a Microsoft popup kind of thing.

Comment: Please look at [`Azure Active Directory B2C`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview) assuming your users are not part of any organization Azure AD.